# $h^0(\mathcal O(p)) \leq 1$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective complex curve of genus $g$ and $D$ an effective divisor. It is true that $l(K-D) \leq g$. I would like to show equality iff $D=0$ or $g=0$. This is Hartshorne IV 1.5. The backwards direction is easy. I would like to show the fowards direction. Assume $D >0$ and $g >0$. Assume for simplicity that $D=p$. We will try to show $l(K-D) < g$. We have the exact sequence:

$$
0 \to \mathcal O(K-p) \to \mathcal O(K) \to \mathbb C_p \to 0.
$$
This, with Serre duality, yields the following long exact sequence:

$$
0 \to H^0(K-p) \to H^0(K) \to \mathbb C  \to H^0(p) \to H^0(\mathcal O) \to H^1(\mathbb C_p)=0
$$
Using additivity of vector space dimension and rearranging a bit we find:
$$
2 - h^0(p) = g - h^0(K-p).
$$
To complete the problem, we must conclude $h^0(p)$ is $0$ or $1$. Why is this the case? It is easy to see $h^0(p) \leq 2$ from $0 \to  H^0 (\mathcal O) \to H^0(\mathcal O(p)) \to \mathbb C$.

Comment: Well, $h^0(p)\ge 1$, since you have the constant functions. On the other hand, if you had a nonconstant function with a simple pole at $p$, wouldn't that give you an isomorphism with $\Bbb P^1$, and so you'd have to have $g=0$?